# make app as device admin

Tags: java, android, adb, device-admin

I am using following code to set app as device admin

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, deviceAdminComponentName); // Here setting my receiver as device admin
intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "You must enable device administration for certain features"
                            + " of the app to function.");
startActivityForResult(intent, 50);
```

After allowing app to to be `device admin` I am executing following code

`devicePolicyManager.setSecureSetting(deviceAdminComponentName, Settings.Secure.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS, "1");`

Here it throws me error 
`Admin component info {...} not set to profile owner..`

I googled and find that `DeviceAdminReceiver` can be made admin by using following adb command

`dpm set-device-owner com.yego.driverkiosk/.DeviceAdminMaker` and it works. but I want it be done from code only .

**DeviceAdminReceiver**

```
public class DeviceAdminMaker extends DeviceAdminReceiver {
@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
   // showToast(context, context.getString(R.string.admin_receiver_status_enabled));
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //showToast(context, context.getString(R.string.admin_receiver_status_disabled));
}

@Override
public void onPasswordChanged(Context context, Intent intent) {
   // showToast(context, context.getString(R.string.admin_receiver_status_pw_changed));
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
}
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it from code only.  These are extremely secure settings.  Basically you're asking for higher authority than the user of the device- superuser authority.  It will never be allowed through another channel, if it was any piece of malware could use it.  These codes are only supposed to be used of devices you physically control, such as kiosks or corporate owned devices.

(Also-  if you set yourself as device policy owner via dpm there's no reason to also make yourself admin, owner is a higher level of admin).